# How to pass in URI variable values to url

Tags: java, spring, rest, url, sbt

Forgive the rookie question--

how do you pass in a the value for a uri variable in a url?

(this is for a spring boot app making a REST call)

for example if I have the url:

```
"http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}"
```

And assuming 'hotel' and 'booking' have String values, how do I pass these in?

Comment: how do you create a requesr? Do you use rest template? If yes then you can pass them as uri variables to the method and template will replace them with values.

Comment: @Reddy yes I use a rest template. right now I'm using `restTemplate.exchange()`

Comment: Someone please give detailed answer to this Question, My scenario is same- I am using restTemplate.exchange() how do i pass variable value from method parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate;
import java.net.URI;

UriTemplate uritemplate= new UriTemplate("http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}");
URI uri = tmp.expand(hotel, booking);
```

Good answers to this question are suprisingly difficult to find.

[Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE_to_3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html#expand(java.lang.Object...)) has some useful examples.

Answer (score -1):

Easy, let's say a {hotel} is called "Casket" and {booking} has value of "Blue"

So your route: `"http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}"`, should look like:

```
"http://example.com/hotels/Casket/bookings/Blue"
```

All you need to do is call that URL and read the response server gives you

Comment: But is there a way to do it without just placing the values in the Url - for example let's say there's a method getHotel() and getBooking() for a particular customer object

Comment: And I want to do something like hotel = customer.getHotel()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You could create request string dynamically, but those values need to be in the URL, that's the whole point of routes like those and that's how the GET requests work.